# Modification of a set of data in Excel using complex criteria

Tags: excel

I need to heavily modify the layout of my data. My starting point is something like (I have a lot of rows, so I would like to use some formula or macro):

```
t1 a
t2 b
t3 c
```

What I'm trying to obtain is:

```
t1 a
t2 a
t2 b
t3 b
t3 c
```

Unfortunately I'm no Excel expert, so I tried with some simple `IF` formulas but with no success. Any idea and suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using Excel in english version.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
In particular, in the first column I have time values in seconds, while in the second column I have ID of a product. For the sake of simplicity let's assume this:

```
time [s]  ID
1         102
3         105
5         110
6         107
```

and what I need to get is

```
time [s]  ID
1         102
3         102
3         105
5         105
5         110
6         110
6         107
```

Obviously time is always incrementing, while the IDs are random.

Comment: Can you explain logic to achieve your output?

Comment: I need it to create a particular kind of plot, which has to look like a stepped line instead of a zig-zag line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in the `A` and `B` columns and that your first row is the "header" row (i.e. a row with just column headers), you can use the following formulas to get the desired results:

```
= INDEX(A:A,FLOOR((ROW()+1)/2,1)+1)

= INDEX(B:B,FLOOR((ROW())/2,1)+1)
```

The first formula, put in cell for example `D2` and the second formula, put in cell for example `E2` and then drag down as far as necessary.

See below for a working example.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot that's exactly what I needed!